# Apple M1 + Another redis desktop manager

Tags: redis

brew install --cask another-redis-desktop-manager

Error message: damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After brew install, use the commands:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Another\ Redis\ Desktop\ Manager.app
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you need only one command:

`sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Another\ Redis\ Desktop\ Manager.app`